# Reasons Spark slowed down

Tags: performance, apache-spark

We have noticed that our Spark recently is not catching up with the data and from time to time it is stalling. The amount of data has increased by few hundred percent in last few weeks, however the load on the servers seems to be minimal.

What could be the possible reasons we should investigate and what would be the first steps to increase the throughput?

Our logs show that the total delay time started increasing at one point:

[image]

It never went down after that, we had to redeploy the Spark job, after which Spark quickly caught up with the lag. What could be the reason for such a behaviour?

Comment: Its very difficult to guess the problem with such short details. From snapshot it looks like your total delay is increasing i.e. your batch processing time increasing than batch interval time. It could be because of lot of reasons. I suggest to add more details.

Comment: @NachiketKate What details would you need please and I will add them? What I find especially intriguing is why the Spark did catch up after the restart.

Comment: Details like batch execution breakdown details, no. of executors and their utilization, spark concurrency etc. would help to identify the problem. I think you should look at batch details when your batch processing time started increasing which can show you component which took longest time in complete batch processing. see if you see similar trend in other batches as well. When you did restart spark, it could catch up because new resources were allocated but did you face similar issue after some time ?